# When can you use a name before it's defined?

Tags: python, sly

In SLY there is an example for writing a calculator (reproduced from `calc.py` [here](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#an-example)):

```
from sly import Lexer

class CalcLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = { NAME, NUMBER }
    ignore = ' \t'
    literals = { '=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')' }

    # Tokens
    NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

    @_(r'\d+')
    def NUMBER(self, t):
        t.value = int(t.value)
        return t

    @_(r'\n+')
    def newline(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')

    def error(self, t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
        self.index += 1
```

It looks like it's bugged because `NAME` and `NUMBER` are used before they've been defined. But actually, there is no `NameError`, and this code executes fine. How does that work? When can you reference a name before it's been defined?

Comment: `Lexer` uses a custom metaclass that handles missing variables.

Comment: There is some *deep* magic going on here - `Lexer` has a metaclass that redefines how its subclasses get defined.  Specifically, the subclasses are no longer using a standard Python dict for their namespace, they're using a dict subclass that automatically defines names (as a string equal to the name) on lookup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python knows [four kinds of direct name lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names): [builtins / program global](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins), module global, function/closure body, and class body. The `NAME`, `NUMBER` are resolved in a class body, and as such subject to the rules of this kind of scope.

The class body is evaluated in a [namespace provided by the metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace), which can implement arbitrary semantics for name lookups. In specific, the sly `Lexer` is a `LexerMeta` class using [a `LexerMetaDict`](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly/blob/06b92e3e735db55b2d53db488785b2acc9d655ac/sly/lex.py#L103-L141) as the namespace; this namespace creates new tokens for undefined names.

```py
class LexerMetaDict(dict):
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self and key.split('ignore_')[-1].isupper() and key[:1] != '_':
            return TokenStr(key, key, self.remap)
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
```

The `LexerMeta` is also responsible for [adding the `_` function to the namespace](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly/blob/06b92e3e735db55b2d53db488785b2acc9d655ac/sly/lex.py#L143-L164) so that it can be used without imports.

```py
class LexerMeta(type):
    '''
    Metaclass for collecting lexing rules
    '''
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(meta, name, bases):
        d = LexerMetaDict()

        def _(pattern, *extra):
            ...

        d['_'] = _
        d['before'] = _Before
        return d
```