# Confusing syntax: either a pylint warning, or a program error using the "sly" lexer

Tags: python, sly

I am using the `sly` lexer to build a simple lexer, and I am a little confused by the Python syntax in this one. The below code works, but I get a syntax warning in my editor, that I am using `OPCODE` before assignment.

```
from sly import Lexer

class AsmLexer(Lexer):    
    tokens = { OPCODE }
    ignore = '\t\n'

    OPCODE          = r'[A-Z]{3}'
```

When I move the `OPCODE` line before `tokens` though, I get this error:

> sly.lex.LexerBuildError: OPCODE does not match a name in tokens

Now, I can live with a pylint warning, but I always want my code to be clean (warnings are bugs in disguise) and I don't really understand why this happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can you use a name before it's defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016983/when-can-you-use-a-name-before-its-defined)

Comment: The TLDR is: ``sly`` use metaclasses to (legally) change the name resolution in the class body. A static code analyzer cannot infer that.